# C# TCPClient - Leave It Open or Close After Each Transmission?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcpclient

I have an industrial application that uses the .NET TcpClient object in C#.

I am simply receiving a short barcode string from two different barcode readers at fairly long, inconsistent intervals. The application works great for awhile, but eventually I get a connection issue with one or the other barcode reader. The connection gets lost, and sometimes the scanner will stop accepting connections until it is restarted.

As the application is now, I create the connection just once. When the scanner is triggered (from another IO device) I get the stream and the barcode comes in fine.

I am wondering if I should instead be waiting for the trigger to do everything at once- i.e. create the connection, get the stream, close the connection and dispose of the TcpClient each trigger. I am hoping this or some other method will keep my devices from dropping their connections and hanging up.

The tough part is that I have no idea what the "servers" (scanners) are doing because I can't debug them.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Simple connection code:

```
private void Connect()
    {
        IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse(IPString);

        try
        {
            TCPClient.Connect(IP, PortNumber);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Connection failed
            Message = "Connection Failed @" + IP;
        }

        if (TCPClient.Connected == true)
        {
            // Connection Succeeded
            Message = "Connection Established @" + IP;
            TCPSocket = TCPClient.Client;
        }
    }
```

Simple Data Receive Code:

```
public bool DataAvailable()
    {
        String data = null;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[256];
        int bytesRead;

        NetworkStream Stream = TCPClient.GetStream();

        if (!Stream.DataAvailable) return false;
        else
        {
            do
            {
                bytesRead = Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            while (Stream.DataAvailable);
        }
        Message = data;
        return true;
    }
```

I also have this simple connection test that gets run on each scanner every minute or so, but I'm pretty sure it's not doing what I intended it to (and it also may be responsible for the drops?):

```
public bool TestConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            return !(TCPSocket.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead) && TCPSocket.Available == 0);
        }
        catch (SocketException) { return false; }
    }
```

Comment: Hmya, this is not supposed to happen.  Yet it does happen, it is not unusual.  An industrial setting tends to be rather unfriendly to simple CAT5 wired network connections.  Somebody starts a large electrical motor and sensitive electronic equipment in a 50 feet radius starts failing.  Could be a firmware bug in the scanners as well, definitely not uncommon.  Best place to start is there, the manufacturer would be most aware of existing problems experienced by their customers.

Comment: Yes, I have reached out to the manufacturer of the scanners. They may even have their own set of .NET libraries to interface with these scanners, but I wanted to keep this application as simple and reusable as possible. I just want to make sure first and foremost that there's nothing wrong with my C# code, or use of these classes.